# Clion IDE syntax analyzer errors on correct Opencv 3.2 syntax

Tags: c++, opencv, ide, clion

In opencv, using a mingw-w64 build of Opencv 3.2 for windows, Currently when I do the following:

```
    cv::Mat test_mat = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1, 0, -1,
            2, 0, -2,
            1, 0, -1);
```

it compiles fine, but the Clion IDE parser claims that "types cv::Mat and int are not compatible", and the solution for fixing this is:

```
    cv::Mat test_mat;
    test_mat = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1, 0, -1, 2, 0, -2, 1, 0, -1);
```

or

```
    int test_mat = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1, 0, -1,
            2, 0, -2,
            1, 0, -1);
```

Obviously the bottom one is just plain wrong. Is there any way to have Clion syntax analyzer correctly parse the initial example as correct syntax?  Again, this is not a compiler error, just an internal IDE syntax analyzer error hint that isn't actually correct.

Comment: Report it as a bug to the IDE developers. Nothing we can help with here if it's a bug.

Comment: @tambre I have no clue if it is actually a bug though, if you have sufficient evidence to say that this is the case, then post an answer so I can accept it and other people can see that this is the issue...

Comment: @tambre  woa there, stop the car, what the heck are you talking about? Doubles can't be negative?  What world do you live in?  Do you know what the double spec looks like for [IEEE standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)?  This is basic, like *really basic* programming.

Comment: I mostly live in a world where I never really need doubles. Oh well. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug in the CLion IDE syntax analyzer. The syntax highlighter probably uses some kind of a grammar to generate the coloring. Syntactically, the statement is valid.

When you infer type information, you can see that the statement is wrong. Doing that for real-time syntax highlighting might be a possible solution - however, I'm not sure how slow it would be across libraries of different scales.